# Circular duplicates aren't handled in an intuitive way

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close

I've been reviewing close votes and found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/639290/permissions-error-when-trying-to-create-virtual-machine) (let's call it Question 1):

[image: Question 1]

But its proposed duplicate (Question 2) is already marked as a duplicate of Question 1.

Still, I've been able to select Question 2 as a duplicate and click *Vote to Close*. That's when the circular duplicate has been detected and prevented.

[image: Question 2 proposed as a duplicate]

I guess what happened here was:

1. Someone voted to close Q1 as a duplicate before Q2 was marked as a duplicate.
2. Daniel Beck has marked Q2 as a duplicate of Q1.
3. I've been asked if Q1 is a duplicate of Q2, but prevented from voting.

Note that Q2's doesn't need to be closed by a moderator, same thing happens when first close vote for Q2 is cast after Q1's first one, but more users vote for Q2.

The system worked at last, but it's not intuitive. I think that when Q2 has been marked as a duplicate, it should be immediately removed from Q1's proposed duplicates. This could prevent some confusion among reviewers.

Comment: My bad. I checked that there were no votes on the question I left open, but didn't consider flags.

Comment: Still, that's a task that could and should be automated. Computers are there to preform routine tasks for humans, right?

Comment: Somehow I thought we did prevent this automatically by clearing suggested closure flags just like you noted - checking on it